# MyPy and explict checking

Tags: python, mypy

```
def sample_method(data: Optional[dict])
        if type(data) is dict:
            return deepcopy(data)
```

This will fail mypy checking

`Argument 1 to "deepcopy" has incompatible type "Optional[Dict[Any, Any]]"; expected "Dict[Any, Any]"`

Is there a way to get mypy to recognise the explicit check on the line above?

Comment: Are you passing some specific argument to mypy? Running mypy on this
```
from typing import Optional
from copy import deepcopy

def sample_method(data: Optional[dict]):
    if type(data) is dict:
        return deepcopy(data)
```
returns no errors

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#complex-type-tests - "Mypy can’t infer the type  after the `type()` check because it only knows about `isinstance()`"